# Undo/Redo Conflict Resolution action in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to undo/redo a conflict resolution in VS2013/TFS?

Accidentally clicked "Use Local Changes" when really meant to do "Resolve Conflicts". Since "Use Local Changes" was clicked the changes are all intact. Is there a way to force VS2013/TFS to resolve conflicts again so this time we can merge?

Comment: No problem: Go to your pending changes and undo your pending changes. Then do the merge again - and do the resolve one more time.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen This is what I usually do too. You should post that as an answer instead of as a comment.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen - this won't work because if I undo the changes then I will lose my changes (the ones I wanted to merge).

Comment: I just ran into this, and it made me miss Git.

Comment: It is important to mention that you are not merging two branches. You are merging a server change with your local change (I guess), that happens when you do a "Get Latest Version". @MortenFrederiksen's comment only is applicable when you are merging two branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Shelve all the changes
2. Undo checkout all changes
3. Unshelve your Shelveset.

The dialog to resolve conflict will appear when you try to check-in

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me.  I had done a merge and mistakenly clicked on Take Target..., then realized that I really wanted to do the 3-way merge.  Now I can't get it to recognize that there's a conflict.  I tried what you suggested here, after trying to simply undo pending changes and merge again, but the merge now simply succeeds, rather than noting the conflicts.  Any other advice?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have no other pending changes than the merge (always check in or shelve any pending changes before you do a merge), you can either undo all changes and do the merge again, or undo the changes of a single file and just merge that file. Do to the latter:

1. Undo the pending change in your target branch
2. Locate the file in your source branch and select merge...
3. Select the same file in your target branch
4. Redo the conflict resolution